# How to copy compositing nodes from on file to another?

Tags: node-editor

I do know if I make a group node of the nodes I want could do this. But is there a better way? Copy-Paste? (Note: I am talking about compositing nodes, not material nodes)

Answer (score 3):

File -> Append -> select your file -> NodeTree -> choose the node group you want.

The same method works for all kinds of data (shaders, meshes, etc.).

EDIT: I just reread your question and realized that for whatever reason you don't want to group the nodes. I think my solution only works for a group of nodes. I don't know if there's a way to do it without grouping them.

Comment: Echows Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Does not work for Blender 2.8+