# Faster way to copy paste nodes from one document to another using Attributes addon

Tags: node-editor

Is there a faster way to copy nodes from one document into another, rather than making the nodes in to a group node tree? if there's a pay add-on please refer it to me.

Thank you.

Comment: if you have 2 Blender opened, you can use the Copy Attributes addon and Ctrl C/Ctrl V to copy/paste from a Blender to another

Comment: so i assume you do it now by append/link right?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73576/how-to-copy-compositing-nodes-from-on-file-to-another

Comment: I'm trying to use the attributes method and I'm getting this error message: https://ibb.co/2Sr1QPb

Comment: oh you're right Copy Attributes doesn't seem to work fine for nodes.

Comment: Hi :). You can't *copy/paste* nodes or materials between two Blender instances. You can, however, *copy/paste* an object which will bring it's material with it :)